# How do getStaticPaths and getStaticProps work together?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have read the Next.js docs, and I know how to work with both getStaticProps and getStaticPaths.

What I'm missing is how they actually work together? I mean when exactly getStaticProps is called (when used with getStaticPaths in a [slug].js file) ?

In my analysis (which I'm not sure of), I think getStaticProps is "some how" called inside the loop of getStaticPaths, so getStaticPaths runs getStaticProps for every object in its "paths" variable, am I right?

Look for my comment in this code snippet:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))
// getStaticProps is called somewhere in the previous loop???

  
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  const post = await res.json()

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { post } }
}

export default Post
```

I also want to confirm another understanding, does getStaticPaths modify the context variable by assigning the params key for each object in the paths array, so when it calls getStaticProps the params will be updated in the context (which both functions have access to) and ready for getStaticProps?

I read the Next.js docs and watched many videos about data fetching in Next.js, but still didn't find the answer to my questions.

Thanks,
Taha

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getStaticPaths` is called first. You return some options and an array of parameters to feed into `getStaticProps`.

`getStaticProps` is then called once for each set of parameters you returned from `getStaticPaths`. This step happens in parallel as well, to speed up the build.

---

**Re "what if you have an extreme amount of paths":**

If you return a million values from `getStaticPaths`, then yes, `getStaticProps` will be called a million times. And yes, that could be very intensive, which is why you in `getStaticPaths` also have the `fallback` property that you can return.

With that you can say what should happen if a client requests a path that has *not* been pre-rendered, and only return the subset of your paths that you *do* want pre-rendered. Could for example be your top 100 blog posts, top 1000 products based on latest analytics, or even an empty list, if you don't want to pre-render anything.

Your fallback options are `fallback: true` and `fallback: 'blocking'`. The first results in Next serving your page [fallback-page](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-pages) with `router.isFallback` set to `true`, while it's generating the missing page (so you then have to deal with that, show a spinner or whatever). And the second, which is much easier, and better for the user as long as your rendering isn't insanely slow (in my opinion), just means that Next will block the response until the rendering is done, and then return the page normally. So in short `true` means you have to implement a spinner (maybe good for super slow pages?), and `'blocking'` means you do not (my preferred one).

See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths for more info.

Comment: I also think it's important to state that the functions are called in separate processes. Therefore you cannot use JS references to share data between the functions.

Comment: concise, good answer

Comment: hello @Svish thanks for your answer, are you saying that if the data returned is over a million in size, like you have a large set of data, - getStaticProps is run for each set of parameters - of the getStaticPaths - isn't that going to be processer intensive - and with soo much load on the server ..  just saying.

Comment: @AndeCaleb Updated the answer with a section on "what if there are super many paths"

Comment: @bas080 When these two functions run in separate processes, how does Next JS ensure that getStaticProps is run after getStaticPaths?

Comment: @KJSudarshan, by having getStaticPaths be run before getStaticProps. The output of getStaticPaths is serialized and passed to the getStaticProps processes.

Comment: @bas080 You are reiterating what Next does which is known to us. I am asking if you can provide the technicalities of how Next does it internally since I am running into an issue where getStaticProps is unable to read the contents of a file which were written to it during getStaticPaths.

Comment: @KJSudarshan Writing any data during `getStaticPaths` or `getStaticProps` sounds like very shaky practice, and I would really recommend not doing that. Those two functions should only read data and return it.